# Who let the dogs out? - Object destruction when "Is-A" meets "Has-A" in a class hierarchy

Tags: c++

Consider this:

```
class FluffyThing
{
public:
  FluffyThing()
  {
    m_pMyFur = new Fur;
  }
  virtual ~FluffyThing();

protected:
  Fur * m_pMyFur;
};

class ClawedFluffyThing : public FluffyThing
{
public:
  ClawedFluffyThing()
    : FluffyThing()
  {
    m_pMyClaws = new Claws;
  }
  virtual ~ClawedFluffyThing();

protected:
  Claws * m_pMyClaws;
};

class ScaryFluffyThing : public ClawedFluffyThing
{
public:
  ScaryFluffyThing()
    : ClawedFluffyThing()
  {
    m_pMyTeeth = new Teeth;
    m_pMyCollar = new SpikedCollar;
  }
  virtual ~ScaryFluffyThing();

protected:
  Teeth * m_pMyTeeth;
  SpikedCollar * m_pMyCollar;
};
```

Hopefully there are not too many mistakes in that - I think you get the idea. The essential point is there are 3 class with an IS-A relationship between them, and each class also HAS-A attribute or two that is going to require some cleanup when it comes to destruction time. If I had not declared the virtual destructors, would the compiler have generated the following for me automatically? Having declared the destructors, and therefore being forced to implement them (assuming the classes are used) is what follows the correct long-hand way to do the destruction?

```
FluffyThing::~FluffyThing()
{
  delete m_pMyFur;
}

ClawedFluffyThing::~ClawedFluffyThing()
{
  delete m_pMyClaws;
  FluffyThing::~FluffyThing();
}

ScaryFluffyThing::~ScaryFluffyThing()
{
   delete m_pMyTeeth;
   delete m_pMyCollar;
   ClawedFluffyThing::~ClawedFluffyThing();
}
```

There is bound to be a definitive answer out there already... but I couldn't lay my hands on it quick enough for my likes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You don't manually call the destructors of base classes, they are called automatically, in reverse order of inheritance. Other than that, it's fine.

```
FluffyThing::~FluffyThing()
{
  delete m_pMyFur;
}

ClawedFluffyThing::~ClawedFluffyThing()
{
  delete m_pMyClaws;
} //will call ~FluffyThing

ScaryFluffyThing::~ScaryFluffyThing()
{
   delete m_pMyTeeth;
   delete m_pMyCollar;
}  //will call ~ClawedFluffyThing
```

Of course, you wouldn't even need the `delete`s if you used RAII (smart pointers instead of raw pointers).

> If I had not declared the virtual destructors, would the compiler have generated the following for me automatically?

No. :) `virtual` destructors are there for correct behaviour in the case you delete a derived class instance through a base class pointer. The following:

```
FluffyThing* p = new ScaryFluffyThing;
delete p;
```

is legal only if `FluffyThing`'s destructor is virtual. Otherwise, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks - I knew that the compiler had to be capable of doing some of the work, but not all of it, and was not clear in my head on where the balance lay. This makes perfect sense to me :-)

Comment: @omatai well, in all fairness, it does do all of the work it's supposed to. It can't delete the pointers because it can't know that the class owns them. For all it knows, they're being created elsewhere and shouldn't even be deleted, right?

Comment: Further reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/07/127826.aspx

Comment: Um, @Luchain, the classes as written are using RAII: if you create it, you destroy it. Smart pointers can help in some cases, but they're not an essential part of RAII, nor should they be used automatically. They introduce overhead that a simple delete doesn't have, and in many cases that overhead is simply waste.

Comment: @jeffamaphone - I actually found that article confusing, and lacking any clear consideration of the "HAS-A" complication. Due to that article and similar ones, I deliberately used "FluffyThing" and so on here rather than "d" or "b" or "foo" or "bar" because these kinds of abbreviations often osbcure the behaviour for people with a certain kind of brain. That is to say... whereas to some brains (mathematical ones) "foo" etc highlight the abstract essence, to others (like mine) these stark abbreviations fail to hold on to any semantic meaning, and all end up looking the same.

Comment: @PeteBecker With the very light-weight smart pointers (eg `scoped_ptr` or `unique_ptr`), there should be zero overhead with any modern compiler -- i.e., they should compile down to raw pointers and all access should be entirely inlined.  It's true that some of the more heavy-weight smart pointers like shared_ptr will introduce some overhead, though.

Comment: @omatai - I agree about that article. It's vague and full of handwaving.

Comment: @Edward - I'd rather not write code than rely on the optimizer to get rid of it. Smart pointers aren't the universal answer that some people think they are. In particular, it's a waste of brainpower, both for the class author and its future maintainers, to wrap a pointer in a class when a simple `delete` will do the same thing.